# Is there a way to start mongodb in read only mode?

Tags: mongodb

I need to disable writes for a mongodb replicaset, is that possible? Something like 'FLUSH WITH READ LOCK'  in mysql?

Comment: Why do you want to disable writes? For backup purposes?

Comment: @wdberkeley replication issues, some members were lagging behind the primary and I couldn't stop writing without stopping reading from the application.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect to secondary directly, not as part of the replica set, then you will not be able to write.

Or you can turn on authentication and create read-only users.

Comment: First one is an interesting one, I wouldn't have thought of that